# Check transparency existence & load only RGB values

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb, alpha-transparency

In order to minimize the memory usage of bitmaps, yet still try to maximize the quality of them, I would like to ask a simple question:

Is there a way for me to check if a given image file (`.png` file) has transparency using the API, without checking every pixel in it?

If the image doesn't have any transparency, it would be the best to use a different bitmap format that uses only the RGB values.

The problem is that Android also doesn't have a format for just the 3 colors. Only RGB_565, which they say that degrade the quality of the image and that should have dithering feature enabled.

Is there also a way to read only the RGB values and be able to show them?

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, this is the second time today you've accidentally created a tag through a typo.  :)

Comment: what was the typo? and what was the previous typo?

Comment: You substituted "androd" for "android" both times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the next links which could be helpful for checking if the png file has transparency . sadly, it's a solution only for png files . rest of the files (like webP , bmp, ...) need to have a different parser .

links:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PNGDecoder.htm

http://hg.l33tlabs.org/twl/file/tip/src/de/matthiasmann/twl/utils/PNGDecoder.java

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,24202

Answer (score 2):

For me `bitmap.hasAlpha()` works fine to check first if the bitmap has alpha values. Afterwards you have to run through the pixels and create a second bitmap with no alpha I would suggest.

Comment: your solution would work after you've succeeded loading the entire bitmap from the file, which means you need to decode it all. this takes more time and could potentially take a lot of memory. after this step, you need to release this bitmap and decode the file again into a bitmap...

Comment: I upvoted this comment, just because it worked for our scenario, we do load it with alpha when we display it, but, to send it to the sever we want to avoid sending png unless is required

Answer (score 1):

Let's start a bit off-topic

> the problem is that android also doesn't have a format for just the 3 colors . only RGB_565 , which they say that degrade the quality of the image and that should have dithering feature enabled.

The reason for that problem is not really Android specific. It's about performance while drawing images. You get the best performance if the pixeldata fits exactly in 1 32bit memory cell.

So the most obvious good pixel format is the `ARGB_8888` format which uses exactly 32bit (24 for the color 8 for alpha). While drawing you don't need to do anything but to loop over the image data and each cell you read can be drawn directly. The only downside is the required memory to work with such images, both when they just sit in memory and while displaying them since the graphic hardware has to transfer more data.

The second best option is to use a format where several pixels fit into 1 cell. Using 2 pixels in 32bit you have 16bit per pixel left and one of the formats using 16bit is the 565 format. 5bit red, 6bit green, 5bit blue. While drawing this you can still work on memory cells separately and all you have to do is to split 1 cell in parts. Due to the smaller memory size required for images, drawing can sometimes be even faster than using 32bit colors. Since in the beginning of android memory was a much bigger problem they chose this format to be the default.

And the worst category of formats are those where pixels don't fit into those cells. If you take just the 3 colors you get 24 bit and those need to be distributed over 2 cells in 3 out of 4 cases. For example the second pixel would use the remaining 8 bit from the first cell & the first 16bit of the next cell. The extra work required to work with 24bit colors is so big that it is not used. And when drawing images you usually have alpha at some point anyways and if not you simply use 32bit but ignore the alpha bits.

So the 16bit approach looks ugly & the 24 bit approach does not make sense. And since the memory limitations of Android are not as tight as they were and the hardware got faster, Android has switched it's default to 32bit (explained in even more details in http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/)

---

Back to your real question

> is there a way for me to check if a given image file (png file) has transparency using the API , without checking every pixel in it?

I don't know. But JPEG images don't support alpha and PNG images usually have alpha. You could simply abuse the file extension to get it right in most cases.

But I would suggest you don't bother with all that and simply use `ARGB_8888` and apply the nice image loading techniques detailed in the Android Training documentation about [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

The reason people run into memory problems is usually either that they have way more images loaded in memory than they currently display or they use giant images that can't be displayed on the small screen of a phone. And in my opinion it makes more sense to add good memory management than complicating your code to downgrade the image quality.

Comment: i see . about 3 bytes vs 4 bytes , isn't the 3 bytes faster than 4 bytes , yet have the same quality? caching would work even better, since it has more useful data for each page, no ? also , in PNG, is it possible to check the transparency existence without going over the pixels , by reading from the header of the file , for example ?

Comment: 3 and 4 byte have the same quality but the graphic hardware will convert 3byte back to 4byte (or 2byte) because internally computers kind of can't work with odd numbers. So yes, the caching itself gets better if you need to cache less but overall you loose efficiency due to the required conversion. -- Android API has afaik no way to determine if a file is saved with alpha, only if decoded `Bitmap`s have alpha. You could write a file header parser or check if there is any library that does this for you.

Comment: i see . is there an open source library that does it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to check if a PNG file has transparency, or at least if it supports it:

```
public final static int COLOR_GREY = 0;
public final static int COLOR_TRUE = 2;
public final static int COLOR_INDEX = 3;
public final static int COLOR_GREY_ALPHA = 4;
public final static int COLOR_TRUE_ALPHA = 6;
private final static int DECODE_BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
private final static int HEADER_DECODE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

/** given an inputStream of a png file , returns true iff found that it has transparency (in its header) */
private static boolean isPngInputStreamContainTransparency(final InputStream pngInputStream) {
    try {
        // skip: png signature,header chunk declaration,width,height,bitDepth :
        pngInputStream.skip(12 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1);
        final byte colorType = (byte) pngInputStream.read();
        switch (colorType) {
        case COLOR_GREY_ALPHA:
        case COLOR_TRUE_ALPHA:
            return true;
        case COLOR_INDEX:
        case COLOR_GREY:
        case COLOR_TRUE:
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Other than that, I don't know if such a thing is possible.